# Excel vba loop to check if below cells below are same and append

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have two columns that goes like this:

```
   Number        Description
    1                a
    2                b
    3                c
    4                d
    5                e
    5                f
    5                g
    6                h
    6                i
```

I want to write a loop that makes the resultant table:

```
   Number        Description
    1                a
    2                b
    3                c
    4                d
    5                e f g
    5                
    5                
    6                h i 
    6
```

Any ideas on how this would be done? I can get it to check if the cell below is the same and append but I'm not sure how to extend the logic so that it keeps on checking if the one below that is the same (like the case with 5 repeating multiple times) so I basically want to keep checking until it's not the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As String
Dim m As String

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
k = Cells(i, 2)
m = Cells(i - 1, 2)

If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
Cells(i - 1, 2) = m & " " & k
Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: please tick the solution and upvote if it helped you